# Dokku Environment Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, docker, digital-ocean, dokku

In one of the dokku plugin's (specifically the dokku-shoreman plugin), I see references to variables like $APP, $1. Where are these variable stored?

I accidentally deleted all of the docker containers and images on my server and after re-deploying, dokku-shoreman is no longer working, instead exiting with status code 1. I think these variables may be the key.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To see all environment variables, `dokku config APP_NAME`

[https://dokku.com/docs~v0.4.11/configuration-management/](https://dokku.com/docs%7Ev0.4.11/configuration-management/)